# Java parallelStream java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

I'm using Hazelcast Jet to do calculations over a large number of elements (~ 480 million).

I'm starting using an IMap Sink containing the starting data. I'm filling the map using

```
 Collections2.permutations(initialPermutation).parallelStream().forEach(set -> {
        Permutation permutation = new Permutation(set);
        permutations.put(permutation.toString(), permutation);
    });
```

where Permutation is a simple data class and set is a List of Integers. When running this parallel stream I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker
```

and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in using the `parallelStream()` to perform blocking work. The Streams API is meant for computational loads, but you have a network load to push through. The implementation of Streams API has code that detects when a thread in its thread pool has entered the blocked state and replaces it with a fresh thread. However, this happens only up to a threshold, and then you get the exception.

Instead, in order to achieve the best throughput into Hazelcast, use batching: split it into chunks and then push to the map using with `map.setAll(chunk)`.

Use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68913656/1103872) to transform your `Stream<Set<Integer>>` into `Stream<List<Set<Integer>>`, something like this (`chunkify()` is defined in the linked answer):

```
chunkify(Collections2.permutations(initialPermutation)).stream().forEach(chunk -> {
    Map<String, String> chunkAsMap = chunk.stream().map(Permutation::new).map(Object::toString).collect(toMap(x -> x, x -> x));
    permutations.setAll(chunkAsMap);
});
```